# I want to integrate the new Google recaptcha with symfony 1.4

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, recaptcha

My application is built with **symfony1.4** and I want to integrate the new recaptcha by Google(v2). The **sfWidgetFormReCaptcha** that comes with the framework seems to use the old version of recaptcha...
I need to know if it's possible to upgrade my plugin in order to use the newest recaptcha ? Is there any other recaptchaPlugin v2 compatible with symfony 1.4 ?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in captcha plugin of symfony 1.4. Below is the link.

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfReCaptchaWidgetPlugin

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this one uses the old version of Recaptcha

Comment: Please try this one.

http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfReCaptchaLibPlugin/1_4_2
http://www.gee.rocks/symfony-1-4-recaptcha-easy-way-to-use/